# Roots of a polynomial must be real

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Say $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $n$ real roots. I have to prove that the polynomial $Q(z)=P(z+i)+P(z-i)$ has $n$ real roots.

First it happens that for a real number $t$ and because $P$ is real polynomial we have $$\overline{Q}(t)= \overline{Q(t)} =\overline{P(t+i)}+\overline{P(t-i)} \\
 = P(\overline{t+i})+P(\overline{t-i}) \\
= P(t-i)+P(t+i) = Q(t) $$
The polynomial $Q-\bar{Q}$ has infinite roots (namely all the real numbers) and thus $Q$ is a real polynomial

Truth is I don't know how to proceed further. This exercice was given at the beginning of a complex analysis course so I don't know if I must search for an analytical argument or a simpler one. If you can **just give me a hint** (I want to solve the problem by myself) that would be really helpful

Comment: Why do you think that $\overline{P(t+i)}=P\left(\overline{t+i}\right)$?

Comment: $P$ is a real polynomial so if $P(X)=\sum a_k X^k$ then $\overline{P(t+i)} = \overline{ \sum a_k (t+i)^k }  = \sum \overline{a_k (t+i)^k} = \sum a_k \overline{(t+i)^k} $ because $a_k$ are real
Am I mistaken ?

Comment: You never claimed that $P(x)$ is a real polynomial (in the sense that its coefficients are real), only that its *roots* are real.

Comment: Well if it has $n$ real roots and it is of degree $n$ I think it is sufficient to conclude that it is a real polynomial don't you agree ?

Comment: If $P(X)=iX$, then all roots of $P(X)$ are real, but $P(X)$ is *not* a real polynomial, right?!

Comment: You are absolutely right. If we suppose that it is monic I think we can conclude that is a real polynomial

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Well I must thank you for pointing that out because in my mind I was considering a monic polynomial but I didn't mention it. My point it, without loss of generality we can consider only monic polynomial of degree $n$ and in that case having $n$ real roots implies that it is a real polynomial

Answer (score 6):

We can write $P(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)$ where $a_j$'s are real roots of $P$. Suppose $Q$ has a non-real root $\alpha+\beta i$. Since its conjugate $\alpha-\beta i$ is also a root of $Q$, we may assume $\beta>0$. Then we have
$$\begin{align*}
|P(\alpha+\beta i+i)|^2 &=\prod_{j=1}^n \left|(\alpha-a_j)+(\beta+1)i\right|^2 \\&=\prod_{j=1}^n \left[(\alpha-a_j)^2+(\beta+1)^2\right]\\&>\prod_{j=1}^n\left[(\alpha-a_j)^2+(\beta-1)^2\right]
\\&=|P(\alpha+\beta i-i)|^2,
\end{align*}$$ leading to the contradiction to that $Q(\alpha+\beta i)=P(\alpha+\beta i+i)+P(\alpha+\beta i -i)=0$. Hence all roots of $Q$ should be real.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $t$ is real, what is the complex conjugate of $t+i$. What does that tell you about $Q$?

Hint 2: This is a heuristic hint. If you know, or assume, that a polynomial has only real roots, then you can assume the polynomial can be put in the for of a product of monomial factors, each of the form $(x-r_i)$, where r_i is a real root of the polynomial.
$$a_n\prod_{i=1}^n(x-r_i)$$

The heuristic hint is this. You will exclude all of the polynomials that have complex roots simply by using that form rather than the form:
$$a_0 +\sum_{i=1}^n a_nx^n$$

Hint 3: If $Q(z)= 0$, with $z\in\mathbb{C}$, what can one say about $|P(z+i)|$ as it relates to $|P(z-i)|$?

Comment: To reinforce this: try a few sample $P$ (e.g. $P(x)=x(x-1)(x+1) = x^3-x$) and see if you notice anything about the resultant $Q$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: using the word "resultant" rather than "resulting" in this context may be inviting people to fish for red herrings.

Comment: @RobArthan I hadn't even considered the terminological overlap, d'oh. Good catch.

Comment: Frankly I still don't see how to solve can you give me another hint please ?

Comment: I'm not sure how big of a hint you want. Did you try a few sample polynomials as @StevenStadnicki suggested?

Comment: @W.314 I added a hint. But I don't know what you have tried, so I don't know whether the hint is too small. Maybe it is something you already realized, and don't know where to go from there. I need more feedback. Also, I am also a newbie on this site, and I'm not sure that it is appropriate to be giving hints, rather than answers. Maybe someone with more seniority may clue me in.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy for your first hint, we can write $Q = P(t+i) + P(\overline{t+i}) = P(t+i) + \overline{P(t+i)} = 2 * Re(P(t+i))$ And I'm stuck there.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I computed $Q$ for you example and I found $Q=2x(x^2-4)$ the roots of $Q$ are 0,-2 and 2 and I don't see a way to map it to the roots of P
I tried to compute $Q$ for the case where $P$ has two roots and I found $Q(t)=2(P(t)-1)$ for this case I don't know how to proceed to infer that the roots of $Q$ must be real
Any further hints will be much appreciated

Comment: @W.314 I have added a new hint for you in the answer box.